# How can I send push notifications from my app on button click to another single user?

Tags: android

I'm looking for a way to send a notification to a single user with a specific phone number upon clicking a button.

Currently, I'm using GCM to send push notifications, but these notifications only function manually.

My code is in Python and was written based on a [tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-get-started-with-push-notifications-on-android--cms-25870).

Answer (score 0):

first of all, i suggest you to change for FCM you may know that are 2 kinds of messages:

downstreams : from app server to mobile app, 
upstreams: from mobile app to app server,

im using the next code to send messages to my mobile app from server:

```
requests.post( set.FCM_URL, json.dumps(  dataReq ), headers )
```

FCM_URL is the route to weathever/send
dataReq is my json object, 
and headers are the content-type & autorization.

im using the "requests" library for python you need to import it first

```
import requests
```

and with that single line im sending downstream messages...

Comment: i want to send notification on button click from my app to first server and then server will send it to the particular user

Comment: when every app get a new token, you need to save those tokens in your server well, that way you can send notifications from server to mobile app to those devices with those tokens,                                                                 from mobile app you can use an asynctask to send a request to your server, indicating that a button is pushed,  then the server check/validate your request and get those tokens it have and send a notification to all devices like the example above.